# How to increase size of JXBusyLabel?

Tags: java, swingx

I've got the following code:

```
  JXBusyLabel label = new JXBusyLabel();      
  label.setBusy(true);
  label.setSize(100, 100);
  frame.add(label);
```

I need a circle indicator of loading, and this code is good. But I need to increase size of circle, because now it has got a very small size. But `setSize` method doesn't allow me to do what I want. Please, tell me, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [swingx javadoc](https://pirlwww.lpl.arizona.edu/resources/guide/software/SwingX/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXBusyLabel.html), you can pass a `Dimension` object to JXBusyLabel like this:

`JXBusyLabel label = new JXBusyLabel(new Dimension(100,84));`